# I cannot get the totals to output properly on the event list

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have events that I have that printout under the dates that they occur, but I need them to print with "Today + the date" or "Yesterday = the date" depending on if this is true or not.

```
    $notes = UsersNote::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get();
    foreach($notes as $note) {
        $activity = [];
        $activity['icon'] = "/assets/icon-activity2-new-note.svg";
        $activity['action'] = "New Note";
        if($note->is_private > 0) {
            $activity['icon'] = "/assets/icon-activity2-new-private-note.svg";
            $activity['action'] = "New Private Note";
        }
        $activity['detail'] = $note->note;
        if(!empty($note->author_id)) {
            $author_name = UsersPermission::withTrashed()->where('user_id','=',$note->author_id)->value('name');
        }
        if(!empty($author_name)) $activity['detail'] = $author_name." wrote: ".$activity['detail'];
        $activity['media'] = "";
        $activity['link'] = "";
        $activity['time'] = strtotime($note->created_at);
        $activity['hourly'] = Format::shortTime($note->created_at);
        $activity['since'] = Format::shortDate($note->created_at);
        if($view == "all" && $note->is_private > 0) $activities[] = $activity;
        else if($note->is_private == 0) $activities[] = $activity;
    }

    // Re-order by date
    usort($activities, function ($a, $b) {
        return ($b['time'] > $a['time']);
    });


// Group
$new_activities = [];
foreach($activities as $activity) {
    if(isset($new_activities[$activity['since']])) $new_activities[$activity['since']][] = $activity;
    else $new_activities[$activity['since']] = [$activity];

    $the_date=strtotime($activity['since']);
    if($the_date = strtotime('today UTC')) {
        "Today ".$the_date;
    } elseif ($the_date = strtotime('yesterday UTC')) {
        "Yesterday ".$the_date;
    } else {
        $the_date;
    }

}
return response()->json(array_values($new_activities), 200);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @senty The list of events only prints out the dates and not with "Today" or "Tomorrow" should they equal up with todays or yesterdays date.

Comment: Probably not the solution to your problem, but `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparisons. Your `if` and `elseif` should both be using `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$new_activities = [];` is a Collection. (If it's an array `collect($array)` to turn it into collection).

You can utilize `map()` to add a field or override an existing field.

```
$activities->map(function($activity) {
    $the_date = strtotime($activity['since']);

    if($the_date == strtotime('today UTC')) {
       $activity['formatted_date'] = "Today ". $the_date;
    } elseif ($the_date == strtotime('yesterday UTC')) {
       $activity['formatted_date'] = "Today ". $the_date;
    } else {
       $activity['formatted_date'] = $the_date;
    }

    return $activity;
})
```

Now check the result with `dd($activities)`.

Comment: that gives me an error "Undefined variable: new_activities" ??

Comment: I added some changes. By the way, I am assuming your if date comparison is correct and `$activities`  is a collection returned from your database.